# Переход на другое activity в fragment'e

Tags: android-fragment, android, java

Есть в проекте Navigation Drawer, в нем я использую фрагменты, в одном фрагменте показывает содержимое активити в котором много кнопок, мне нужно осуществить переход с этих кнопок на другое активити, как перейти не знаю!

**MyActivity.java**

```
package tren.SportPit.ru;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity; import
android.app.ActivityManager; import
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context; import
android.os.Build; import
android.os.Bundle; import
android.view.Gravity; import
android.view.LayoutInflater; import
android.view.Menu; import
android.view.MenuItem; import
android.view.SurfaceView; import
android.view.View; import
android.view.ViewGroup; import
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyActivity extends
ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks
{

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and
presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link
#restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int
position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager =
getFragmentManager();
        android.app.Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position){
            case 0:
            fragment = new Upraznenia();
                break;
            case 1:
            fragment = new Eat();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new Programmy();
                break;
        }

      fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
              .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
              .commit();

    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {

        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen())
{
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my,
menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for
this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int
sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER,
sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MyActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }

}
```

**Upraznenia.java**

```
package tren.SportPit.ru;

import android.app.Fragment; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

 public class Upraznenia extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_upr,
container, false);
        return rootView;
    } 
}
```

Comment: 1. Зачем вы вывалили сюда весь код, который нашли?    
2. За вас тут ни кто ни чего не собирается делать. @katso вам ответил, как запускать активити.    
3. Отформатируйте нормально ваш код. У меня кровь начинает течь из глаз, когда я смотрю на все это изобилие цветов и шрифтов.    
4. Если вы хотите, что бы сделали "очень срочно" и "вместо вас", обращайтесь на фриланс биржи. Там сделают быстро и недорого.    
5. Вы и правда пишете весь код в одну строчку?

Comment: Нет, это когда сюда вставил, всё форматировалось, я же говорю я пока что еще чайник, и пока что только учусь все делать. Я вроде бы не писал чтобы все сделали за меня, я не могу разобраться, вы написали мне строчку кода, для вас, знающего человека, она, наверняка, и дала ответ на мой вопрос, но для меня это строка кода, которую я только наполовину понимаю. Разве этот ресурс создавался только для " прошареных хацкеров" ? По мойму здесь может задать вопрос как новичок, так и тот же "Хацкер". А Katso огромное спасибо, единственны отнесся с пониманием.

Comment: @alex11, этот ресурс создан для новых вопросов, которые ни где в другом месте еще не задавались. Если это сделали за вас, то попросите того же, кто сделал и поправить. Если вы не понимаете, как это сделать, то вы и не начнете понимать, если сделают за вас. Если вы хотите понимать - учите с самого начала по урокам. Если не хотите - заплатите кому ни будь что бы сделали за вас.

Comment: @Expert ♦♦ я снова предлагаю вам перестать заниматься фигней. Кто вас просил превращать мой комментарий в ответ? Или вы думаете, что вы лучше знаете, что я хотел оставить ответ, или комментарий??

Comment: Я учился по урокам "СтартАндроид", но там такого нету, я задал вполне адекватный вопрос, но тут же налетели, что отбивает желание задавать вопросы. А если и есть уроки по этой теме, то они на английском или Испанском, что не дает мне возможности разобраться полностью в этой теме. И спасибо тому, кто отредактировал за меня.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), NewActivity.class));
```

Comment: Можно поподробнее я просто еще чайник совсем, а уроков малова-то по андрюше, приходится разбирать очень долго, надеюсь поможете

Comment: @alex11 маловато уроков?? вы издеваетесь?? их на столько много, что жизни человеческой не хватит, что бы все пересмотреть!

Comment: @alex11, вызывайте этот метод во фрагменте, NewActivity - имя нового активити, [подробнее о запуске активити][1] 


  [1]: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/58-urok-21-sozdanie-i-vyzov-activity

Comment: @alex11, во фрагменте 

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Button button = getView().findViewById(R.id.button);
    }

Comment: private Button btnSheya;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = null;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_upr, container, false);
        btnSheya = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sheya);
        btnSheya.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sheya:
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), lay_sheya.class));
                break;

        }

Comment: Теперь вылетает при нажатии на кнопку, уже бьюсь об заклад, никак не могу решить проблему.

Comment: @alex11, с какой ошибкой? Вы наверняка забыли прописать активити в манифест!

Comment: Спасибо вам, все работает.